# state do not change with useContext

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-context, use-context

**hello**

I am trying to make a menu toggle, where I have a variable with false as initial value, using react createContext and useContext hook, I set the initial state as true

```js
// useMenu Context
import React, { useContext, useState } from 'react'

export const useToggle = (initialState) => {
  const [isToggled, setToggle] = useState(initialState)
  const toggle = () => setToggle((prevState) => !prevState)
  // return [isToggled, toggle];
  return { isToggled, setToggle, toggle }
}

const initialState = {
  isMenuOpen: true,
  toggle: () => {},
}

export const MenuContext = React.createContext(initialState)

const MenuProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const { isToggled, setToggle, toggle } = useToggle(false)
  const closeMenu = () => setToggle(false)
  return (
    <MenuContext.Provider
      value={{
        isMenuOpen: isToggled,
        toggleMenu: toggle,
        closeMenu,
      }}>
      {children}
    </MenuContext.Provider>
  )
}
export default MenuProvider

export const useMenu = () => {
  return useContext(MenuContext)
}
```

so If true it will show the Menu if false it will show the Div where there a div

**App.js**

```js
const { isMenuOpen } = useMenu()

//the providder
<MenuProvider>
  <Header mode={theme} modeFunc={toggleTheme}/>
      {isMenuOpen ? (
         <Menu />
      ) : (
      <Switch>
        <Route path='/writing' component={Writings} />
        <Route path='/meta' component={Meta} />
        <Route path='/contact' component={Contact} />
        <Route path='/project' component={Project} />
        <Route exact path='/' component={Home} />
        <Route path='*' component={NotFound} />
      </Switch>
    )}
  <Footer />{' '}
</MenuProvider>
```

and when I add an onclick event the NavLink button of the menu to close it it does not work

**Menu**

```js
const { closeMenu } = useMenu()
// return statement
{paths.map((item, i) => {
  return (
    <MenuItem
      key={i}
      link={item.location}
      svg={item.icon}
      path={item.name}
      command={item.command}
      onClick={closeMenu}
     />
  )
})}
```

where did I go wrong

Comment: Just to be clear, can you please elaborate on what exactly the `<Menu />` is doing right now? Is it "staying open"?

Comment: @MichaelHoobler it's a component that contains a list I thought I explained in the last piece of code where MenuItem represents a NavLink component

Comment: @Jargarkin, I meant what is the "unintended behavior" as in: what exactly is component *currently doing* compared to what the component *should be doing*".

Comment: @MichaelHoobler the intented behavior was to hide menu when `isMenuOpen` false but when change it to false it always stays as true, problem resolved it was the wrong placement of the Provider

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Issue

I suspect the issue is in `App` where you've a `useMenu` hook *outside* the `MenuProvider` used *in* `App`. This `useMenu` hook is using a `MenuContext` context but in the absence of a provider it instead uses the default initial context value.

```
const initialState = {
  isMenuOpen: true,
  toggle: () => {},
};

export const MenuContext = React.createContext(initialState);

export const useMenu = () => {
  return useContext(MenuContext)
};
```

[React.createContext](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html#reactcreatecontext)

> ```
> const MyContext = React.createContext(defaultValue);
> ```
>
> Creates a Context object. When React renders a component that
> subscribes to this Context object it will read the current context
> value from the closest matching `Provider` above it in the tree.
>
> *The `defaultValue` argument is **only** used when a component does not
> have a matching Provider above it in the tree.* This default value can
> be helpful for testing components in isolation without wrapping them.

## Solution

Since I doubt you want to run/provide more than one menu provider I believe the solution is to move `MenuProvider` out of and wrap `App` to provide the context you are updating by nested components.

App.jsx

```
const { isMenuOpen } = useMenu();

...

<>
  <Header mode={theme} modeFunc={toggleTheme}/>
  {isMenuOpen ? (
    <Menu />
  ) : (
    <Switch>
      <Route path='/writing' component={Writings} />
      <Route path='/meta' component={Meta} />
      <Route path='/contact' component={Contact} />
      <Route path='/project' component={Project} />
      <Route exact path='/' component={Home} />
      <Route path='*' component={NotFound} />
    </Switch>
  )}
  <Footer />
</>
```

index.jsx (?)

```
import App from './App.jsx';

...

//the provider
<MenuProvider>
  <App />
</MenuProvider>
```

Comment: it worked, I suspected that `MenuProvider` and it's placement in the code has to do something with the state freeze, but since it will wrap on the entire component I just let in App.jsx, this was a learning experience, thank you